# Adding code-completion to Jetbrain's CLion IDE?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm writing a CPython extension using Jetbrain's CLion IDE and I was hoping to get code-completion working for functions and variables inside of Python.h.

I looked through the preferences and I can't find anything relevant.  How do I add code completion and inspection for included libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLion uses the `CMakeLists.txt` in your project to control the lookup paths for code completion and other features -- because your library includes are build specific, it makes sense in a way to put this here.

To the specific question of how to get the `Python.h` library signatures into autocomplete, your CMakeList file should have something like the following:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m")
```

Where `-I/path/to/file.h` is the local path to the directory that contains the header files that you want to include in your build (and by proxy, your autocomplete lookup for the project).